# Python - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyown'

Tags: python, pip, python-import

so i'm making my first telegram bot, and when compiling code in ConEmu I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "echobot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyown
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyown'
```

help me please.

Comment: Looks like you haven't installed `pyown`. You can install it with: `pip install pyowm`

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyown
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyown'
```

Are you sure that the library is called pyow**n**, not pyow**m**?

https://pypi.org/project/pyowm/

Answer (score 0):

It can't find `pyown` library. Install this library first, either to your working folder's library folder or install it globally. Then import `pyown` library on your py file. Then write rest of the codes.

Comment: I have installed pyown library. I'm maked weather forecast program with pyown, and in this project pyown working, but in echobot - don't working.